# Polynomial Chaos: How are the pdfs calculated from the response surface?

Tags: probability, orthogonal-polynomials, orthogonality

Lets assume one has the following response surface: $y(x,\xi) = \sum^N_{i=0} c_i H_i(\xi)$. Where $\xi$ is Gaussian and $H_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Hermite polynomial. I've seen a lot of papers show the PDF of y - but how are they calculating it? One way would be to randomly sample $y$ I guess - but many papers give the analytical pdf. i.e. no sampling and I can't see how?

Cheers Guys!

Answer (score 0):

One could sample $y$ and approximate the coefficients $c_i$. This is the only tenable solution when the distribution of $y$ is unknown.

However, consider the crux of the polynomial chaos approach: we compute the deterministic coefficients using a Galkerkin method, *viz.*

$$c_i = \frac{1}{\langle H_i^2 \rangle} \langle y H_i \rangle.$$ Using the integral representation of the inner product, the latter term becomes

$$
\langle y H_i \rangle = \int_D y H_i(\xi) w(\xi)\ d\xi. \label{eq}\tag{1}
$$

However, this is meaningless as it is -- the support of $y$ and $\xi$ are almost certainly different.

To reconcile this, we recognize that $y$ and $\xi$ are fully-correlated and use an inverse transform. That is, write the *cumulative distribution function* of $y$ and $\xi$ as the same uniform random variable $u \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$:

$$F(y) = u = G(\xi).$$

Therefore, we may define

$$h(u) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} F^{-1}(u) = y \\
l(u) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} G^{-1}(u) = \xi$$

and substitute this into $\ref{eq}$ above.

Note that the CDF is *much* easier to get from sampled data than the PDF.

In the event that the distribution of $y$ is known... well, then we have the PDF anyhow!

Comment: Thanks Arkamis, great thanks I think I can see how that works. I'm actually more interested in the multi-dimensional case where y depends upon many $\ix$'s. in that case presumably I set $F(y) = G(\xi_1,\xi_2 \dots \xi_n)$ i.e the Joint PDF of $\xi$'s?

Comment: This paper might be helpful : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4589927&casa_token=2G6nbcKrcoAAAAAA:N-zU7x5vHCjXmoEzvJwhaOFWIhhWBiDR1CRkMBZiq6Q2oDedJW0rVAhkmZcRRHoHtHNfTBNJ5A&tag=1